# add ID to Value instead of auto numric Jcombobox from mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have mysql DB with costumer table include two records : id 1 name omar , id 3 name ahmad .
I used this class to get and set ID and Name

```
public class ComboItem 
{
private int index;
private String name;

public ComboItem(int pindex, String pName)
{
    this.index = pindex;
    this.name = pName;
}

public int GetIndex()
{
    return this.index;
}

public String GetName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public void SetIndex(int pindex)
{
    this.index = pindex;
}

 public void SetName(String pName)
{
    this.name = pName;
}
```

Main class

```
private void FillNameComboBox(JComboBox combo) throws IOException{
    try{
        combo.removeAllItems();
        Connect c =new Connect();
        Statement stmnt= c.MakeConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rset=stmnt.executeQuery("select idCostumer,Name from Costumer");
        while(rset.next()){
            int index=Integer.parseInt(rset.getString("idCostumer"));
            String name=rset.getString("Name");
            ComboItem ci=new ComboItem(index, name);
            combo.addItem(ci);
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(NameComboBox, e);
    }
}
```

whenever I run the app it keeps giving my the index not the ID ... What should I do ?[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pmxz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dear Omar
you can give an ID and name to Jcompobox by doing the following

1- first create a class of Compo box lets give it name "ComboItem" and do the following:

public class ComboItem 
{

```
private int index;
private String name;
private String col;

public ComboItem(int pindex, String pName) {
    this.index = pindex;
    this.name = pName;
}

public ComboItem(int pindex, String pcol, String pName) {
    this.index = pindex;
    this.col = pcol;
    this.name = pName;

}

public int GetIndex() {
    return this.index;
}

public String GetName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String GetCol() {
    return this.col;
}

public int SetIndex(int pindex) {
    this.index = pindex;
    return pindex;
}

public String SetName(String pName) {
    this.name = pName;
    return pName;
}

public String SetCol(String pCol) {
    this.col = pCol;
    return pCol;
}

// This will be used internally by JComboBox as the label to be displayed.
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

// to get the Index of Combobox depends on ComboItem Class
public static int getIndexById(JComboBox combo, int id) {

    for (int i = 1; i < combo.getItemCount(); i++) {
        try {
            ComboItem c = (ComboItem) combo.getItemAt(i);
            int tempId = c.GetIndex();
            if (tempId == id) {
                return i;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

after that you will be able to set and get the compo box Items in other classes as the following:

Set Items Id and Name

```
     try
    {
        combo.removeAllItems();
        conn = Operations.SqlConnector();
        String sql = "select EmpID, EmpName from Emp";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ComboItem nullValue = new ComboItem(0,"- select -");
        combo.addItem(nullValue);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            int index = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("EmpID"));
            String name = rs.getString("EmpName");
            ComboItem c = new ComboItem(index,name);
            combo.addItem(c);
            c.GetName();
        }
        pst.close();
        rs.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

get Items ID Or Name

```
ComboItem dept = (ComboItem) ComboBox_DeptID.getSelectedItem();
int deptID = dept.GetIndex();
```

and you can use also GetIndexByID() as the following:

```
int dept = ComboItem.getIndexById(ComboBox_DeptID, BindList().get(index).GetDeptID());
        ComboBox_DeptID.setSelectedIndex(dept);
```

best regards.